# Converting point shapefile to polygon shapefile python

Tags: python, gdal, geopandas

I have been trying to convert one of Sentinel-5P ([Sentinel-5P Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dJdhQspdI3p5YyyiBBiNxUPCCOU91QrU/view?usp=sharing)) dataset (viz. 'methane_mixing_ratio_precision') to GeoTIFF file. The plot of one of its dataset viz. 'methane_mixing_ratio_precision' using the below code is [methane_mixing_ratio_precision](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14k3YYwX2h1ZrhY8yWPB28LYPorkdkKri/view?usp=sharing):

```
import xarray
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
netcdf_fname = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\NC Files\CH4_1.nc'
xds = xarray.open_dataset(netcdf_fname, group='PRODUCT')
plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
ax = plt.axes()
xds.methane_mixing_ratio_precision[0].plot.pcolormesh(ax=ax, x='longitude', y='latitude',add_colorbar=True, cmap='jet');
```

Till now I have successfully created a point shapefile ([Point Shapefile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bPE3ssiN4upyStThPuZMHew-Myzngwos/view?usp=sharing)) of the above mentioned dataset. Now I want to convert this point shapefile to polygon shapefile which then I can rasterize to get GeoTIFF file as shown in [methane_mixing_ratio_precision](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14k3YYwX2h1ZrhY8yWPB28LYPorkdkKri/view?usp=sharing).

Using @gene suggestion, I was successfully able to create a buffer (7Km x 7Km) around each point geometry using geopandas:

```
import geopandas as gpd
points = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\NC Files\methane_mixing_ratio_precision_points.shp')
points.geometry= points.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.buffer(0.063, cap_style = 3))
points.to_file(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\NC Files\methane_mixing_ratio_precision_points_buffer.shp')
```

What I basically want is to create a grid (inclined in nature) of (5.5 Km * 3.5 Km) around each point geometry and that grid should like [Section of Methane Plot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18eNMK40UZQzpzUVoY3mhC6BQRjHKrX7p/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

When you buffer the points GeoDataFrame with `buffer = points.buffer` the columns of the original points are not preserved

```
points.head(3)
   Param       Lat        Lon                  geometry
0  3.964342  5.185295  71.578270  POINT (71.57827 5.18530)
1  3.910507  5.206082  71.648300  POINT (71.64830 5.20608)
2  3.990862  5.226586  71.717873  POINT (71.71787 5.22659)
buffer = points.buffer(0.126, cap_style = 3)
buffer.head(3)
0    POLYGON ((71.70427 5.31130, 71.70427 5.05930, ...
1    POLYGON ((71.77430 5.33208, 71.77430 5.08008, ...
2    POLYGON ((71.84387 5.35259, 71.84387 5.10059, ...
```

A solution

```
# copy the original GeoDataFrame to preserve the columns
buffer = points.copy()
buffer.geometry= buffer.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.buffer(0.126, cap_style = 3))
buffer.head(3)
  Param       Lat        Lon                                           geometry
0  3.964342  5.185295  71.578270  POLYGON ((71.70427 5.31130, 71.70427 5.05930, ...
1  3.910507  5.206082  71.648300  POLYGON ((71.77430 5.33208, 71.77430   5.08008, ...
2  3.990862  5.226586  71.717873  POLYGON ((71.84387 5.35259, 71.84387 5.10059, ...
buffer.plot(column='Param')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @gene. "from shapely.geometry import buffer" is throwing following error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'buffer' from 'shapely.geometry' (C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\Sentinel-5P\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\__init__.py)".

Comment: Sorry eliminate thé line